# How to get error trace for the eclipse errors.?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, java-17

When I build the run project it gaves me an error
[image]
then when I tried to run it, it gave me another error
[image]
but no much details behind that

how to get error trace from eclipse & fix it.?

Thanks

I tried with deleting .project .classpath .settings files
also, eclipse clean build
as well as mvn eclipse:eclipse then mvn clean install

it works perfect with mvn exec:java 
but not works with eclipse run-as application

**Error log updated**

[image]

Error log shows below, but not much information in there..

-----------------Exceptions at Build time-----------------

```
eclipse.buildId=4.26.0.20221201-1200
java.version=17.0.5
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -data file:/C:/Users/w127940/ws--2212-eclipse/ -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.core.resources
Error
Thu Mar 02 08:14:01 CET 2023
Errors occurred during the build.

eclipse.buildId=4.26.0.20221201-1200
java.version=17.0.5
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -data file:/C:/Users/w127940/ws--2212-eclipse/ -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.jdt.core
Error
Thu Mar 02 08:14:01 CET 2023
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project '****Service'.

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.QualifiedTypeReference.getTypeBinding(QualifiedTypeReference.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.internalResolveType(TypeReference.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveSuperType(TypeReference.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.findSupertype(ClassScope.java:1670)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectSuperclass(ClassScope.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectTypeHierarchy(ClassScope.java:1454)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectMemberTypes(ClassScope.java:1143)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectTypeHierarchy(ClassScope.java:1464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.connectTypeHierarchy(CompilationUnitScope.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.completeTypeBindings(LookupEnvironment.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.internalBeginToCompile(Compiler.java:881)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.beginToCompile(Compiler.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.compile(BatchImageBuilder.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.buildInternal(Workspace.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.build(Workspace.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BuildAction$1.runInWorkspace(BuildAction.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)


eclipse.buildId=4.26.0.20221201-1200
java.version=17.0.5
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -data file:/C:/Users/w127940/ws--2212-eclipse/ -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.core.resources
Error
Thu Mar 02 08:13:59 CET 2023
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.QualifiedTypeReference.getTypeBinding(QualifiedTypeReference.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.internalResolveType(TypeReference.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveSuperType(TypeReference.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.findSupertype(ClassScope.java:1670)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectSuperclass(ClassScope.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectTypeHierarchy(ClassScope.java:1454)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectMemberTypes(ClassScope.java:1143)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectTypeHierarchy(ClassScope.java:1464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.connectTypeHierarchy(CompilationUnitScope.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.completeTypeBindings(LookupEnvironment.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.internalBeginToCompile(Compiler.java:881)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.beginToCompile(Compiler.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.compile(BatchImageBuilder.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.buildInternal(Workspace.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.build(Workspace.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BuildAction$1.runInWorkspace(BuildAction.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

-----------------Exceptions at Run time-----------------

```
eclipse.buildId=4.26.0.20221201-1200
java.version=17.0.5
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -data file:/C:/Users/w127940/ws--2212-eclipse/ -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui
Error
Thu Mar 02 08:15:04 CET 2023
Internal Error

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaApplicationLaunchShortcut.findTypes(JavaApplicationLaunchShortcut.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaLaunchShortcut.searchAndLaunch(JavaLaunchShortcut.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaLaunchShortcut.launch(JavaLaunchShortcut.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.launch(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.runInternal(LaunchShortcutAction.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.runWithEvent(LaunchShortcutAction.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1090)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$8(ActionContributionItem.java:1206)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3642)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.run(ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.lambda$26(ProgressManager.java:836)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.busyCursorWhile(ProgressManager.java:869)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.busyCursorWhile(ProgressManager.java:845)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.run(ProgressManager.java:1003)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.MainMethodSearchEngine.searchMainMethods(MainMethodSearchEngine.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaApplicationLaunchShortcut.findTypes(JavaApplicationLaunchShortcut.java:165)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.QualifiedTypeReference.getTypeBinding(QualifiedTypeReference.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.internalResolveType(TypeReference.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveSuperType(TypeReference.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.findSupertype(ClassScope.java:1670)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectSuperclass(ClassScope.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectTypeHierarchy(ClassScope.java:1454)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectMemberTypes(ClassScope.java:1143)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectTypeHierarchy(ClassScope.java:1464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.connectTypeHierarchy(CompilationUnitScope.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.completeTypeBindings(LookupEnvironment.java:589)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.accept(MatchLocator.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getType(PackageBinding.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.findType(Scope.java:2025)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getTypeOrPackage(Scope.java:3500)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:3187)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.SingleTypeReference.getTypeBinding(SingleTypeReference.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.internalResolveType(TypeReference.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:625)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve(LocalDeclaration.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve(LocalDeclaration.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(MethodDeclaration.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolve(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1503)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1628)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.process(MatchLocator.java:2033)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1400)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.JavaSearchParticipant.locateMatches(JavaSearchParticipant.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.findMatches(BasicSearchEngine.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.search(BasicSearchEngine.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine.search(SearchEngine.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.MainMethodSearchEngine.searchMainMethods(MainMethodSearchEngine.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.MainMethodSearchEngine$1.run(MainMethodSearchEngine.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)


eclipse.buildId=4.26.0.20221201-1200
java.version=17.0.5
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -data file:/C:/Users/w127940/ws--2212-eclipse/ -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui
Error
Thu Mar 02 08:15:04 CET 2023
InvocationTargetException

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.run(ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.lambda$26(ProgressManager.java:836)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.busyCursorWhile(ProgressManager.java:869)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.busyCursorWhile(ProgressManager.java:845)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.run(ProgressManager.java:1003)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.MainMethodSearchEngine.searchMainMethods(MainMethodSearchEngine.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaApplicationLaunchShortcut.findTypes(JavaApplicationLaunchShortcut.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaLaunchShortcut.searchAndLaunch(JavaLaunchShortcut.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaLaunchShortcut.launch(JavaLaunchShortcut.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.launch(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.runInternal(LaunchShortcutAction.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.runWithEvent(LaunchShortcutAction.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1090)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$8(ActionContributionItem.java:1206)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3642)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.QualifiedTypeReference.getTypeBinding(QualifiedTypeReference.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.internalResolveType(TypeReference.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveSuperType(TypeReference.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.findSupertype(ClassScope.java:1670)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectSuperclass(ClassScope.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectTypeHierarchy(ClassScope.java:1454)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectMemberTypes(ClassScope.java:1143)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectTypeHierarchy(ClassScope.java:1464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.connectTypeHierarchy(CompilationUnitScope.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.completeTypeBindings(LookupEnvironment.java:589)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.accept(MatchLocator.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getType(PackageBinding.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.findType(Scope.java:2025)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getTypeOrPackage(Scope.java:3500)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:3187)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.SingleTypeReference.getTypeBinding(SingleTypeReference.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.internalResolveType(TypeReference.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:625)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve(LocalDeclaration.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve(LocalDeclaration.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(MethodDeclaration.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolve(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1503)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1628)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.process(MatchLocator.java:2033)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1400)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.JavaSearchParticipant.locateMatches(JavaSearchParticipant.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.findMatches(BasicSearchEngine.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.search(BasicSearchEngine.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine.search(SearchEngine.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.MainMethodSearchEngine.searchMainMethods(MainMethodSearchEngine.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.MainMethodSearchEngine$1.run(MainMethodSearchEngine.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

Comment: Generally you would check the Error Log for more details than what the dialog might show.

Comment: @nitind : error attached, but not much info in there

Comment: In the _Error Log_ view, please delete the error log first and then reproduce the issue to avoid to get unrelated things log items. Then select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_. Currently you question shows only the stack trace which is only a part of what is logged and it's unclear whether it is related to the error dialog you get.

Comment: @howlger : Thanks for you comment, I've again tried to build and run project. so logs updated as you mentioned

Comment: The stack trace looks like [this bug](https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.core/issues/790) which is being worked on